# Nintex Workflow 2013 - How to access workflow variable in Configure Action - Query XML output?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, nintex

I have an action that as existing outputs. An example of one of them is

```
Process Using: [XPath]
/my:myFields/my:supervisorCheck

Return results as: [x]Text []Inner XML []Outer XML
Store result in: [sSupervisorSignOff]
```

I see that **sSupervisorSignOff** is a Workflow Variable, so I have created a variable called **sOshaRecordable** with the type of Yes/No. The default value is No, and "Show on start form" is unchecked (just like all the other variables).

The problem that I am running into is that when I create the new output in the action

```
Process Using: [XPath]
/my:myFields/my:OshaRecordable

Return results as: [x]Text []Inner XML []Outer XML
Store result in: []
```

the "Store Result In" field lists all the other variables *except* sOshaRecordable.

I have read the help documentation which just says

```
Store result in

Use the drop-down to specify where the resulting text should be stored.
More than one output value may be entered. To specify additional output select 
Add output and fill in the required information.
```

I have looked everywhere on Google, and I can't figure out why this variable is not showing up. So, I come to you lovely people seeking wisdom.

What am I missing? How do I fix this?